# How to transform GroupedObservable<String, Message> to SectionModel<String, Message> using Groupby operator of RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I want to show date as section title and group the messages as per their date.
I want to use RxDatasource library and having trouble to create SectionModel to feed directly to datasource.

```
let source = sut.results.asObservable().map { result -> Observable<Message> in
    switch result {
    case .success(let messages):
        return Observable.from(messages)
    default:
        break
    }
    return Observable.from([Message]())
    }
    .flatMap { $0 }

let group = source.groupBy { $0.date.dateOnly }
group.subscribe(onNext: {
   print($0)
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Below is the output I get in log:

```
GroupedObservable<String, Message>(key: "2017-01-01", source: RxSwift.(GroupedObservableImpl in _FBBDBB31E5DDAA1ED24286DA8D9FFB1F)<Swift.String, Tacos.Message>)
GroupedObservable<String, Message>(key: "2017-01-02", source: RxSwift.(GroupedObservableImpl in _FBBDBB31E5DDAA1ED24286DA8D9FFB1F)<Swift.String, Tacos.Message>)
```

I am not able to find out the way to transform                `GroupedObservable<String, Message>` => `Observable<SectionModel<String,Message>>`

The JSON which is converted to `Message` is as in the image:
[json description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPZeU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        let messages = [
            Message(id: 1001, msgContent: .Text("TextContent1"), sender: .Host, date: "2017-01-01T01:00:00.000Z".dateFromISO8601!),
            Message(id: 1002, msgContent: .Text("TextContent2"), sender: .Guest, date: "2017-01-01T01:00:00.000Z".dateFromISO8601!),
            Message(id: 1003, msgContent: .Text("TextContent3"), sender: .Host, date: "2017-01-01T01:00:00.000Z".dateFromISO8601!),
            Message(id: 1004, msgContent: .Text("TextContent4"), sender: .Host, date: "2017-01-02T01:00:00.000Z".dateFromISO8601!),
            Message(id: 1005, msgContent: .Text("TextContent5"), sender: .Host, date: "2017-01-02T01:00:00.000Z".dateFromISO8601!),
            Message(id: 1006, msgContent: .Text("TextContent6"), sender: .Guest, date: "2017-01-02T01:00:00.000Z".dateFromISO8601!),
            Message(id: 1007, msgContent: .Text("TextContent7"), sender: .Host, date: "2017-01-03T01:00:00.000Z".dateFromISO8601!),
            Message(id: 1008, msgContent: .Text("TextContent8"), sender: .Guest, date: "2017-01-03T01:00:00.000Z".dateFromISO8601!),
            Message(id: 1009, msgContent: .Text("TextContent9"), sender: .Host, date: "2017-01-03T01:00:00.000Z".dateFromISO8601!),
            Message(id: 10010, msgContent: .Text("TextContent10"), sender: .Host, date: "2017-01-03T01:00:00.000Z".dateFromISO8601!)
        ]

        let source = Observable.from(messages)

            let group = source.groupBy { $0.date.dateOnly }
            group.flatMap {
                Observable.combineLatest(
                        Observable.just($0.key),
                        $0.toArray())
                }
                .map { date, messages in
                    Observable.of(MessageGroup(header: date, items: messages))
                }
                .subscribe(onNext: {
                    print($0)
                }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is:

```
    messages
        .map {
            Dictionary(grouping: $0, by: { $0. date.dateOnly })
                .map {
                    SectionModel(model: $0.key, items: $0.value)
                }
        }
        .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(dataSource: tableViewDataSource))
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't quite understood you, but maybe

`let group = source.groupBy { $0 }.flatMap { $0.asObservable() }`

is what you're trying to achieve?

**UPDATED:** (but without generics for SectionModel)

```
let group = source
    .groupBy {
        return $0
    }
    .switchLatest()
    .map { text -> SectionModel in
        return SectionModel(title: text)
    }
```

Comment: If we do that then the `group` will be of type Observable<Message> and we equivalent to `source` I want some to know how to transform   `group`  into `GroupedObservable<String, Message>` => `Observable<SectionModel<String,Message>>`

Comment: please check out the flat list of Messages as given in the JSON file
I want to convert it in to `Observable<SectionModel<String, Message>>` which i will use to bind to rxdatasource to display the table of Messages grouped by the date.

Answer (score 0):

```
func grouredBy() {
    var section = Observable.from(transactions)
    var group = section.groupBy { $0.txnDate }
    group.flatMap { (listOFT) -> Observable<(String?, [TransactionListModel])> in
        var superH =  Observable.combineLatest(Observable.just(listOFT.key),
                                          listOFT.toArray().asObservable())
        return superH
    }.map { date, messages in
        Observable.of(SectionModel(model: date, items: messages))
    }
    .subscribe(onNext: {
        print($0)
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```